# Is it ok to keep simple C++ method definitions inside of a header file?

Tags: c++, oop

I've put all of my classes into separate header files. So I have a file named `snake` for the `Snake` class and a `fruit` file for a `Fruit` class etc. I'm familiar with the concept of using a header file for declaring a class and its methods and then defining the methods in a separate `.cpp` file with the same name. All of that makes sense to me and I've done that in the past.

My question is: Is it considered a bad practice to implement the simplest methods inside the header file without a separate `.cpp` file? Or maybe I should put the whole class in the `.cpp` file instead?

The reason why I'm asking this is that some of my classes only consist of 2 or maybe 3 *set* and *get* member functions and I don't see a point in creating a separate file for less than 10 lines of code. In fact I believe it would make my code unnecessarily complicated. I looked online and some people say it's fine, others say it's not.

Comment: Template methods cannot be defined in a separate cpp file, so there are cases that defining methods in C++ header is good.

Comment: This is inherently a matter of style. Personally I think simple getters/setters are ok in header files. However in your case are you sure a simple struct with public members wouldn't be better?

Comment: This is opinion-based. But I tend to define functions in headers if I care about performance, since then those functions may be inlined.

Comment: If your classes only have a few getters and setters and no other member functions, you might as well remove them and use public member variables.

Comment: It's fine to put short function definitions like setters and getters inside the class definition. What you must avoid is _declaring_ them inside the class, and then _defining_ them in the header file but outside the class (you probably know this already).

Comment: “some of my classes only consist of 2 or maybe 3 set and get member functions” — Then they’re probably not very good classes, and could benefit from refactoring. The whole point of OOP is to bundle *behaviour* with your data. If the data has no behaviour it’s just a bag of values. This can be OK but then why bother with setters and getters?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to keep simple C++ method definitions inside of a header file.  That's fairly common practice.  Especially for small projects.  Large projects, the team may impose a convention to avoid inline methods in the headers to reduce churn and incremental build overhead.

Comment: @TonyK • Do you mean **Foo.h** `class Foo { int x; public: int get() const; void set(int);}; inline int Foo::get() const { return x; }` the method defined in the header but outside the class must be avoided in a header?  (Assume that `set` is in the **Foo.cpp**.)

Comment: @Eljay: well. that `inline` makes it OK of course. But I was only posting a comment, so I couldn't cover everything.

Comment: @TonyK: Didn't mean that personally ,was just a bit blunt. Everybody (thus me included) from time to time makes such statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ReinstateMonica left a really good, succinct answer which I wholeheartedly agree with -- however I wanted to expand a little on it.

There is nothing inherently "good" or "bad" about defining functions inline in a header. There can be some cases where it is better to not define in a header since it may cause code-bloat; but this is something that would be determined after examining the product.

What matters most is that your code is easy to read and understand, because this increases maintainability -- it doesn't matter whether someone else will be the maintainer, or if its yourself a year from now.

In my experience working in large projects in C++, it becomes common to rely on header files as the form of "living documentation" in order to see what functionalities are introduced in any given header at a glance. Having code be simple to digest at a glance makes a *huge* difference on how quickly new code can be written using this API.

Function definitions that are written inline in the class definition can upset that readability by interrupting the natural flow. For example, consider the following two code snippets which are equivalent:

```cpp
class Snake
{
public:

   auto get_name() -> std::string
   {
      return m_name;
   }

   auto eat(const Fruit& fruit) -> void
   {
        ..
        // some really long definition
        ..
   }

   auto set_name(std::string name)
   {
      m_name = std::move(name);
   }
};
```

Contrast this to the more succinct, but still inline:

```cpp
class Snake
{
public:

    auto get_name() const -> std::string;

    auto eat(const Fruit& fruit) -> void;

    auto set_name(std::string) -> void;
};

inline auto Snake::get_name() const -> void
{ 
    return m_name;
}

inline auto Snake::eat(const Fruit& fruit) -> void
{
    ..
    // some really long definition
    ..
}

inline auto Snake::set_name(std::string) -> void
{
    m_name = std::move(name);
}
```

By simply relocating the definitions to the bottom and explicitly marking these `inline`, we get a quick topological view of the `Snake` class and all related actors and observer functionalities on it without having to scan between function definitions.

This will not change code generation in the slightest, but it can help to improve readability of the class by making it self-documenting -- which can be very useful if you work in a team environment, or ever have someone else come in to maintain your project.

Answer (score 1):

1. The split between header and "source" files is only done for humans. As far as the compiler is concerned, you need a single source file - a single translation unit - say `foo.txt`, and produce an executable directly from it. The file can have any name - doesn't need to end with `.cpp` or `.h` - that's to make life easier for humans, too. The compiler doesn't care one iota.
2. Having said that, it's completely up to you, and the coding style of the project you work on. You **absolutely, positively must do whatever improves the readability, cohesion and understandability of the code**. Compiler? That one comes *last*.

Comment: Well, a header file is typically compiled multiple times, so any function definitions in it should be implicitly or explicitly inline or static in order to avoid duplicate symbol definitions.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I wanted to make sure that it's not conceptually wrong.

Comment: @Marsellus Conceptually definitely not. There are even cases where you must put the definitions in headers (or "headers" according to this answer ;), such as for function templates or functions with return type deduction.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Sure, but that's not something that you can do unaware. The linker will scream at you. Although, if you're good to yourself and enable unity builds from the moment you created the project - as you normally should, to speed compilation up - the unity build might hide that problem until the build system decides to change the assignment of source files to translation units. Unity builds are perhaps the most two-faced buggers I've ever ran into. Shifty little bastards, too. I still recommend them - it's better than meeting someone like them in real life :)

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of separating headers and source files is reducing build dependencies. If you define a function in a header, any time you change that function you have to recompile every source file that uses that header. If you define a function in a source file, any time you change that function you have to recompile the one source file that defines it. For small projects that might not matter much. For larger projects it significantly reduces the time needed to rebuild the project, so reduces turnaround time, making development go faster.

So, no, it doesn't really make sense to put "simple" functions in header files. That doesn't eliminate the build dependency. Once a project has settled down, and there aren't significant changes being made to various parts of it, it might makes sense to move critical functions into header files, not for convenience, but because then you can mark them `inline` and maybe get a performance boost.